# Как изменить символ перед определенным словом

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, файлы

Задача: Перед каждым словом  BACKSPACE  в файле нужно убрать 1 символ.

К примеру: в файле следующие данные: Hello user BACKSPACE .

После выполнения программы, должно получиться: Hello use BACKSPACE .

```
 with open('log.txt', 'r') as f:
 old_data = f.read()

 new_data = old_data.replace(' BACKSPACE ', 'на_что_меняем')

 with open('log.txt', 'w') as f:
 f.write(new_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно во всём тексте убрать букву перед `' BACKSPACE'`, используйте регулярные выражения:

```py
import re

s = ""
with open('log.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()
    # если после BACKSPACE тоже должен быть пробел - в первых кавычках добавляем \s, а во вторых - пробел
    # т.е. re.sub(r".\sBACKSPACE\s", " BACKSPACE ", s) 
    s = re.sub(r".\sBACKSPACE", " BACKSPACE", s) 
with open('low.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Comment: Помогло, но сначало не работало, выдавало TypeError, решил это замеой readlines на read

Comment: А как изменения сделать не в отдельный файл, а в первоначальный?

Comment: @lakvak точно так же - открыть `log.txt` вместо `low.txt`. Старые данные из файла удалятся, а новые запишутся

Comment: Это не сработает в моём случае(